# ExtJS place menu button on modal panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, drop-down-menu, menu, panel

I have modal panel, which closes when I press out of bounds. I want to add button menu on it, but when I press any menu item the panel closes. Is there is possibility to prevent panel close on button menu press?

Some parts of code:

button on panel:

```
    Ext.define('Plugin.dashboard.component.info.JobInfoView', {
    extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.job-info-view',
....
    dockedItems : [ {
        xtype : 'toolbar',
        dock : 'bottom',
        items : [ {
            itemId : 'job-actions-combo',
            text : '<b> Available job actions</b>',
            width : 200,
            glyph : Glyphs.getGlyph('tree'),
            hidden : true,
            shim:true
            bind:{
                menu : '{jobActionsMenuItms}',
                visible : '{jobHasCommands}'
            }
        }
.....
```

showing Panel like tooltip:

```
    showTooltip : function(id) {
        var task = gantt.getTask(id);
        if (!task) {
            return;
        }

        var items ={
            xtype : 'job-info-view',
            jobId : id,
            phase : task.jobPhase
        };

        var list = Ext.Element.select('div[task_id="' + id + '"][class*="gantt_task_line"]', true).elements;

        if (list.length > 0) {
            var cmp = Ext.get(list[0].dom);
            var el = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                style : {
                    backgroundColor : 'white'
                },
                maxWidth : null,
                autoHide : false,
                items : items,
                itemId : 'job-info-view-tooltip'
            });
            el.on('hide', function() {
                Ext.defer(function() {
                    el.destroy();
                }, 1);
            });
            el.showBy(cmp);
        }
    },
```

Comment: Is there a reason you won't use modal `Ext.window.Window` instead of `Ext.tip.ToolTip`?

Comment: tooltip apears near the object I click, I do not need to calculate position.

Comment: you can use the component's `showBy` function to let the framework do the calculating

Comment: what about solution in my situation, as I do not want to change `tooltip` to `Window`?

Comment: Even though `tooltip` is technically derived from `panel`, I doubt it is supposed to include `items`, especially interactive ones like `menu`. Tooltips are typically used for showing just text/html. I guess there *is* a solution to your situation, but it would involve creating some custom overridings of handling the `mouseout`/`mouseleave` events on tooltips.